# Create new array variable inside loop in python3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

```
r = 6371e3 # metres
latBS = 41.178210
lonBS = -8.597820
φ1 = latBS * math.pi/180 # φ, λ in radians
l = 0


dist=[] 
RSRP=[]

paths = ["pathA", "pathB", "pathC", "pathD0", "pathD1", "pathD2", "pathD3", "pathE", "pathF", "pathG0", "pathG1", "pathG2","pathG3"]

for x in paths:
    logFile = pd.read_csv('export/4G_{}.FMT'.format(x), sep='\t')
    logClean = logFile.dropna(subset=['All-Latitude', 'All-Longitude'])
 
    dist.clear()
    RSRP.clear()

    for index, row in logClean.iterrows():
    
        latMS=row['All-Latitude']
        lonMS=row['All-Longitude']

        φ2 = latMS * math.pi/180
        Δφ = (latMS-latBS) * math.pi/180
        Δλ = (lonMS-lonBS) * math.pi/180
        a = math.sin(Δφ/2) * math.sin(Δφ/2) + math.cos(φ1) * math.cos(φ2) * math.sin(Δλ/2) * math.sin(Δλ/2)
        c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
        d = r * c
        dist.append(d) # in metres
        RSRP.append(row['All-Serving Cell RSRP (dBm)[1]'])
```

With this current code, the 4G_pathA.FMT file is read and then processed in a loop where distance is measured between a pair of geographical coordinates. Those values are then stored in the array dist().
However, I would like to store those values in 13 different arrays, each one correspondent to each path in the paths[] array, so that dist_pathA, dist_pathB, etc. and RSRP_pathA, RSRP_pathB, etc.
How can I create a new array inside a loop using the x value in the for loop as the name? I have tried

```
dist_{}.format(x)=[]
```

but to no avail.

Cheers

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, create a dictionary where the `path` is the key, and the array is the value.  That's much easier to work with.

Comment: You are trying to apply string processing function to an identifier names. Some languages (Tcl, notoriously) practice indirect variable naming regularly, but in Python this pattern is not recommended, nor is it as simple as what you write. What you really want is a dictionary or list of lists, as Tim Roberts suggests.

Answer (score 0):

example to store data inside arrays created/populated inside a loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict

arrays_dict = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(10):
  arrays_dict[i].append(<something>)
```

then after the loop ends, you have each key representing the array name and value the array content